# Independent and identically distributed question (Please help check the answer)

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

Please help me check my answer. The question is:
[image]

My calculation I think it's quite simple that's why I'm not too sure. I used the theorem

> $E(X_1 + X_2+X_3+... +X_n) = E(X_1) + E(X_2) + E(X_3) + ... +E(X_n)$

So I got

$= E(X_1)E(X_2) + E(X_2) - E(X_1^2)$

$= 1 + 1 - 1$

$= 1$

Is this the right answer? Thank you!

Comment: $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ , that means $E(X^2)=2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that

$\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2 + X_3 - X_1^2) = \mathbb{E}(X_1X_2) + \mathbb{E}(X_3) + \mathbb{E}(X_1^2) = \mathbb{E}(X_1)\mathbb{E}(x_2) + \mathbb{E}(X_3) + [var(X_1) + (\mathbb{E}(X_1))^2] = 1 + 1 - (1 + 1) = 0 $

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help!